# BinaryVariant Issue when creating Service Reference to SDL Web 8 Content Service

Tags: content-delivery, odata, binary, iis-and-asp.net, microservices

I am using Visual Studio to create a Service Reference to the SDL Web 8 Content Service. This is working quite well. When I load a BinaryVariant using a browser query I see something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/client/v2/content.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryVariants(BinaryId=529,PublicationId=777,VariantId='WyNkZWYjXQ==')</id>
    <title>/web/Images/favicon_tcm777-529.ico</title>
    <updated>2016-07-04T20:11:26+00:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name></name>
    </author>
    <link href="BinaryVariants(BinaryId=529,PublicationId=777,VariantId='WyNkZWYjXQ==')" title="BinaryVariant" rel="edit"/>
    <link href="BinaryVariants(BinaryId=529,PublicationId=777,VariantId='WyNkZWYjXQ==')/Binary" title="Binary" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Binary"/>
    <category term="Tridion.ContentDelivery.BinaryVariant" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:PublicationId m:type="Edm.Int32">777</d:PublicationId>
            <d:BinaryId m:type="Edm.Int32">529</d:BinaryId>
            <d:VariantId>WyNkZWYjXQ==</d:VariantId>
            <d:Path>/web/Images/favicon_tcm777-529.ico</d:Path>
            <d:Description m:null="true"/>
            <d:IsComponent m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsComponent>
            <d:URLPath>/web/Images/favicon_tcm777-529.ico</d:URLPath>
            <d:Type>image/x-bmp</d:Type>
            <d:StructureGroupId m:null="true"/>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

This looks great, but the BinaryVariant class which is generated doesn't have `StructureGroupId` property. Does anyone know why this might be missing, and how I can force Visual Studio to generate the class correctly.

The C# code currently crashes when I do something like this:

```
BinaryVariant test = cdService.BinaryVariants.FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following error:

```
The property 'StructureGroupId' does not exist on type 'ODataService.BinaryVariant'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.
```

Comment: Can you use SDL .Net CIL which contain these classes ? I think there may issue with metadata in these OData V2 entities which may be causing this error.

Comment: I would love to use CIL, but that would mean rewriting the whole DD4T  provider that I have. This is an interim step before we migrate the whole app to DD4T 2.0 with CIL, so not realistic to rewrite twice. Do you think that this is a bug I should submit to support?

Comment: Looks to be a bug as problem appears to be missing info in metadata.

Comment: Is that something I can fix easily? or is it hidden in a JAR somewhere?

Comment: Metadata is generated by service. I am not sure if this can be fixed at the client side. Needs to be investigated properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer Support have confirmed this is a bug. There will be a hotfix for this shortly.